# Recover Lie algebra bracket from the root system

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, root-systems, dynkin-diagrams

I have coordinates of the $n$ roots in the $d$-dimensional space forming the root system of the $(n+d)$-dimensional Lie algebra. I want to implement the algorithm to recover the Lie bracket of the algebra.

1. The Lie bracket between the elements of the Cartan subalgebra is, by definition, zero:
   $$[x_i, x_j] = 0.$$
2. The Lie bracket between the $i$-th cartan subalgebra element and a root element is equal to the $i$-th coordinate of the root times the root element:
   $$[x_i, e_{\vec{\alpha}}] = \vec{\alpha}_i \cdot e_{\vec{\alpha}}. $$
3. How do I recover the Lie bracket between two roots? It can be shown to be proportional to the root element corresponding to the vector addition in the root space. I am interested in the proportionality coefficient.

**Question:** given two roots $\vec{\alpha}$ and $\vec{\beta}$ what is the easiest way to compute the proportionality coefficient $c$ in

$$ [e_{\vec{\alpha}},\, e_{\vec{\beta}}] = c \cdot e_{\vec{\alpha}+\vec{\beta}}. $$

**Update: question 2:** when $\vec{\beta} = - \vec{\alpha}$ the Lie bracket is proportional to the linear combination of the Cartan subalgebra elements, right? Is it only true if $\vec{\beta} = - \vec{\alpha}$? How to calculate the proportionality coefficients (are they just coordinates of the root vector)?

P.S. I know this involves solving the recursive relation, but I am just looking for a general "easy to use" formula or rule for $c$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, what you are looking for is naturally set in what is usually called a *Chevalley basis* and, in particular, *Chevalley's structure constants* $N_{\alpha, \beta}$. Up to their signs, they are determined relatively easily from the root system, as we have

$(N_{\alpha, \beta})^2 = (r+1)^2$

where $r$ is the maximal integer such that $\beta-r\alpha$ is a root. See most books on that topic or [T. Tao's blog entry (lemma 42)](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/04/27/notes-on-the-classification-of-complex-lie-algebras/#more-6629). Of course we can write this as

$N_{\alpha, \beta} = \pm(r+1)$

but determination of the signs for each pair needs more subtle considerations. There is an algorithm going back to Carter, see his book on *Simple groups of Lie type*. [These notes of Casselman's](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b4d9/2b652099e00c0724678c22700a4f0a2b8db4.pdf) give an overview about various approaches.